# Dúvida com visibilidade de método e propriedade no PHP

Tags: php, semântica

Qual a finalidade de declarar funções iniciadas com underline?

Eventualmente me pergunto o porque disto.

Por exemplo:

```
protected function _exemplo() {}
```

Não basta declarar assim?

```
protected function exemplo() {}
```

Tem algum outro motivo específico declarar a função iniciada por underline, quando a própria declaração já usa o limitador de visibilidade `protected`?

**Bônus:** Se existe outro motivo, isto se restringe apenas a métodos ou também a propriedades?

Exemplo(algo parecido com isso, apenas me passou pela cabeça):

```
protected _$var
```

Exemplos de uso em propriedades no CakePHP 2.5:

```
    protected $_associationKeys = array(
    'belongsTo' => array('className', 'foreignKey', 'conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'counterCache'),
    'hasOne' => array('className', 'foreignKey', 'conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'dependent'),
    'hasMany' => array('className', 'foreignKey', 'conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'offset', 'dependent', 'exclusive', 'finderQuery', 'counterQuery'),
    'hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('className', 'joinTable', 'with', 'foreignKey', 'associationForeignKey', 'conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'offset', 'unique', 'finderQuery')
);

/**
 * Holds provided/generated association key names and other data for all associations.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_associations = array('belongsTo', 'hasOne', 'hasMany', 'hasAndBelongsToMany');

// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart

/**
 * Holds model associations temporarily to allow for dynamic (un)binding.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $__backAssociation = array();
```

No exemplo acima, usaram 2 underlins, como um método mágico, mas não é!

Exemplo de uso em método no cakephp 2.5:

```
    protected function _findAll($state, $query, $results = array()) {
    if ($state === 'before') {
        return $query;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: pode colocar o link para este código ? (Github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usar underline antes de um método ou de uma variável não é uma regra geral, mas sim uma convenção de escrita que é adotada em um projeto.

Antigamente víamos muitos projetos com este modo de escrita, porém hoje em dia não tenho visto bons projetos adotando padrões assim, afinal, o PHP evoluiu muito e podemos identificar a visibilidade de muitos modos sem precisar esta marcação.

Imagine se você precisar alterar a visibilidade de um método? Terá de reescrever todas as ocorrências? Isto não é bom.

Eu, particularmente, adoto lowerCamelCase como padrão de nomes de variáveis e métodos, e de preferência, usando prefixos comuns, como `get`, `is`, `has`...

```
//...
protected function hasSomething()
{
```

Exemplo de uso usando métodos mágicos e underline:

```
class Tools
{
//...

    protected function _foo()
    {
        return 'bar';
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments = null)
    {
        $method = '_' . $name;
        if (method_exists($this,$method)) {
            //Chamando metodo interno    
            return $this->$method($arguments);
        }

        //Chamando funçao global
        return $name(current($arguments));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
$tools = new Tools;
echo $tools->foo(); // bar
$tools->var_dump($_SESSION); //Var dump do array Session
```

Em algum momento do futuro, você poderá fazer a sobrecarga de `var_dump`, implementando o método `_var_dump`.

Comment: Mas pelo que eu entendi, é só na declaração, e não na utilização, da mesma forma que usamos o `protected` somente na declaração, estou olhando a lib do framework cakephp 2.5 e usam bastante esta marcação.

Comment: Se você tem uma declaração de uma forma mas o uso de outra, possivelmente está passando por um método mágico, por exemplo, verificando se existe um método interno iniciando com underline e entregando o interno caso exista, ou entregando o nativo php caso não exista. Ou seja, uma engenharia que permite sobrecarga, mas é bem específico do objeto.

Comment: Não, métodos mágicos são duas underlines, neste caso somente um mesmo, como no exemplo acima.

Comment: que tal nos enviar o link github deste objeto que você está estudando ?

Comment: Postei exemplos

Comment: Veja o exemplo que publiquei ao final da resposta

Comment: Ficou mais claro, mas e quanto ao método iniciado por dupla underline? Como um método mágico? Métodos mágicos são nativos do php não é? ou é possível declarar um método mágico?

Comment: O método com dois underlines, se não é mágico, diz respeito a uma particulariedade do projeto ou então, como na resposta do @CIRCLE, segue uma convenção antiga

Answer (score 2):

É de facto uma convenção de programação tal como diz @gpupo e é usado para ajudar a identificar, na leitura de um código, quais as propriedades e/ou métodos que são `private` ou `protected`.

Sendo que:
Um underscore `_` é usado para propriedades e/ou métodos `protected`
Dois underscores `__` é usado para propriedades e/ou métodos `private`

Tal como explica @John Conde [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554860/2011284)

Por exemplo:

```
public     $id;
protected  $_name;
private    $__surname;

public function setId(){
    //... Public Access
}

protected function _setName(){
    // ... Protected Access
}

private function __setSurname(){
    // ... Private Access
}
```

No entanto, segundo sei, esse tipo de convenção era mais usado no início pelos programadores de PHP e hoje já não é tanto utilizado dado às optimizações significativas que PHP tem sofrido.

Comment: Pois é, e aquela dupla underline na propriedade `public $__backAssociation = array();`
Estranho não?

Comment: @Marcelo actualizei a resposta

Comment: Pois é. No início não tínhamos as palavras de visibilidade no PHP 4 e a semântica era importante.

Comment: exactamente, e tinha-se de recorrer muito a comentários no código para não perder o fio à meada

Comment: Segundo o manual do php, esse duplo underline não é recomendado usar:
_"O PHP reserva todas as funções com nomes começando com __ como mágicas. É recomendado que você não use funções com nomes com __ no PHP a não ser que você queira alguma funcionalidade mágica documentada._"